# Data Factory Data Flow sink file name

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a data flow that merges multiple pipe delimited files into one file and stores it in Azure Blob Container. I'm using a file pattern for the output file name concat('myFile' + toString(currentDate('PST')), '.txt').

How can I grab the file name that's generated after the dataflow is completed? I have other activities to log the file name into a database, but not able to figure out how to get the file name.

I tried @{activity('Data flow1').output.filePattern} but it didn't help.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use GetMeta data activity to get the file name that is generated after the data flow.